# subsets of different vectors R

Tags: r

I have three vectors as shown below.

```
q = c("a == 1", "a == 2", "a == 3")
w = c("b >= 50", "b >= 100")
t = c("c >= 40 & c <= 80", "c > 80")
```

I want to be able to combine all the vectors into one large vector so that every possible subset is in a larger vector. For example I want to have

```
("a == 1 & b >= 50", "a == 1 & b >= 100", "a ==2 & b >=50",
"a == 2 & b >= 100", "a == 3 & b >= 50", "a == 3 & b >= 100",
"a ==1 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a ==1 & c > 80",
"a ==2 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a ==2 & c > 80",
"a ==3 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a ==3 & c > 80",
"b  >= 50 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "b >= 50 & c > 80",
"b  >= 100 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "b >= 100 & c > 80", 
"a == 1 & b >= 50 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a == 1 & b >=50 & c > 80",
"a == 2 & b >= 50 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a == 2 & b >=50 & c > 80",
"a == 3 & b >= 50 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a == 3 & b >=50 & c > 80")
"a == 2 & b >= 100 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a == 2 & b >=100 & c > 80",
"a == 3 & b >= 100 & c >= 40 & c <= 80", "a == 3 & b >=100 & c > 80")
```

So I need every subset to be created and joined with the "&" sign but I don't want to be comparing any element in the same vector. I also have three vectors in this example but the number of vectors should be variable. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(q, w, t), sep = " & "))`

Comment: Or may be `combn(list(q, w, t), 2, FUN = function(x) do.call(paste, c(x, sep = " & ")), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Almost! I also need just 2 elements in the vector as well. This code seems to always be taking 1 element from each vector but I also need just q compared to w as well for example. So for example like the first entry in my example "a == 1 & b >= 50 " does not exist

Comment: Please check the modified code

Comment: Hmm I think some elements are missing in the modified code but its almost there! For example (b >= 50 & c > 80) is missing as well as the combinations with 3 elements

Comment: Please update your post with the whole expected output for crosschecking

Comment: Just updated it, left out the last few with all three elements but let me know if you want me to add them in

Comment: If you add all those, it helps others to crosscheck with their attempt

Comment: I think I got all the cases updated

Comment: I get 2 more combinations `unlist( lapply(2:3, function(i) combn(lst, i, FUN = function(x) do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(x), sep = " & ")), simplify = FALSE)))`

Comment: @akrun what does lst contain? I am not able to run it

Comment: And you pretty much have it thanks for the help! I just need all of them combined into a single vector

Comment: sorry `lst  <- list(q, w, t)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Oh wait, when I add a fourth vector it is missing entries with elements from all 4 vectors

Comment: If there are 4 vectrors, you need `lapply(2:4, `

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create strings using `expand.grid` and `combn`.  Create a `combn` of `list` ('lst') elements picking 2 or 3 in a `list` (using `lapply`), expand the `list` elements into a `data.frame` and `paste` with `do.call` (specifying the `sep` as `" & "`)

```
lst <- list(q w, t)
unlist( lapply(2:3, function(i) combn(lst, i, 
    FUN = function(x) do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(x), sep = " & ")), 
         simplify = FALSE)))
```